# How to make a text-type input-element accept just a numerical value (decimal, positive and negative) by ignoring invalid characters on each keypress?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, sanitization, html-input

I have an HTML input and this input just accept the string of number character,

Example:

input value: `+0123.534534` or -234234.543345 or `-13453`, these input values are valid.
The characters + or - just exist one and at first position in string value

I want every typing character the input value should keep the current valid string and replace the invalid input character with an empty character

Example:

When I typed : `+123.g` ==> the value should replace immediately `+123`.
Or when I typed: g ==> the value should replace immediately with an empty value.

I found an implementation with this, but It lack of (+/-/.) character

```
const getDigitsOnly = (value) => String(value).replace(NOT_NUMBERS, '');
```

Comment: Why does the OP not restrict the user input by a number type input field like with ... `<input type="number"/>`?

Comment: Because the value here is not exactly a number, it accepts a range of number characters.

Comment: *"...  it accepts a range of number characters."* ... isn't this a number then?

Comment: ([+-]*[0-9]+.[0-9]+) this is a regex which is accepting your inputs but it can null the value for e.g.: "g==>" will not be accepted but you have to clear the field

Comment: Any `type="text"` and custom validation based approach, if done properly, has the tendency to grow more complex since, from a UX perspective, an immediate value sanitizing (while typing or pasting) also has to take care of reestablishing the user's most recent caret position.

Comment: _"When I typed : `+123.g` ==> the value should replace immediately `+123`"_ Why `+123` and not `+123.`? If `+123.` isn't valid, do you want to immediately replace it with `+123` or is this an additional special case that has to be handled separately?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace it immediately with +123. (just remove alpha character in this case)

Comment: @nhlinh is `.123` a valid input ?

Comment: @nhlinh Please answer my previous comment!

Comment: @h-sifat, No it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution for it.

We add an `input` event listener to the input box and for every input we format the entire input value.

**Note**: Don't forget to trim trailing decimal point (e.g. `"123."` to `"123"`) if exists when submitting the value.

```js
const inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");

inputBox.addEventListener("input", () => {
  inputBox.value = format(inputBox.value);
});

function format(str) {
  if (!str.length) return str;

  str = str.replace(/[^.+-\d]/g, "");
  const firstChar = str.charAt(0);
  str = str.slice(1).replace(/[+-]/g, "");

  // Bug fix. Credit goes to @Peter Seliger
  // For pointing out the bug
  const charArray = [];
  let hasDecimalPoint = false;

  if (firstChar === ".") {
    if (!str.includes(".")) {
      hasDecimalPoint = true;
      charArray.push("0.");
    }
  } else charArray.push(firstChar);
  // End bug fix

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const char = str.charAt(i);

    if (char === ".") {
      if (hasDecimalPoint) continue;
      if (!i && firstChar !== "0") charArray.push("0");
      hasDecimalPoint = true;
    }

    charArray.push(char);
  }

  return charArray.join("");
}
```

```html
<p>Enter your number here</p>
<input id="inputBox" type="text" />
```

**The algorithm of the format function.**

```
1: If the input is empty then return the input
2: Remove all characters except "-", "+", "." and digits
3: Store the first character in a variable
4: Remove all "+" and "-" (if exists) after the first character
5: if the first character is "." then replace it with "0."
6. Finally remove any duplicate decimal point (".") if exists
```

And here are some dummy data to test the format function

```js
const dummyData = [
  "",
  "+",
  "-",
  ".",
  ".123",
  "+.123",
  "123.3.23",
  "12sfdlj3lfs.s++d_f",
  "12--++.123",
];
```

Comment: @nhlinh I think you've accepted the wrong answer. `Micahel Hamami's` answer doesn't pass all the test cases that I've provided in my answer. Please accept `Peter Seliger's` or my answer. And according to your comment `.123` (and  also probably `+.123` and `-.121`) is invalid.  My algorithm will successfully handle those situation by prepending `0.`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger That would be part of form validation. Not the job asked in the question. You can simply check it with `Number.isSafeInterger` or method like that.

Comment: @PeterSeliger By the way I tried and I can neither type not paste the value `0.0.0000345435434354350924390`!? I doesn't allow duplicate decimal point!

Comment: Wait lemme see. Thanks for the feedback <3

Comment: @PeterSeliger and `nhlinh` I've fixed the bug. Thanks a lot Peter <3.

Answer (score 2):

From the above comments ...

> *"Why does the OP not restrict the user input by a number type input field like with ... `<input type="number"/>`?"*

> *"Any `type="text"` and custom validation based approach, if done properly, has the tendency to grow more complex since, from a UX perspective, an immediate value sanitizing (while typing or pasting) also has to take care of reestablishing the user's most recent caret position."*

Proving the above mentioned complexity ...

```js
function stripNeedlessDataFromBoundFieldValue() {
  this.value = this.value.replace((/[-+.]$/), '');
}

function getSanitizedValue(value) {
  value = value
    // remove any leading and trailng whitespace (sequences).
    .trim()
    // remove any character not equal to minus, plus, dot and digit.
    .replace((/[^-+.\d]+/g), '');

  if (value.length >= 1) {

    let partials = value.split(/(^[+-]?)/);
    if (partials.length === 1) {

      partials.unshift('');
    } else {
      partials = partials.slice(1);
    }
    let [ first, last ] = partials;

    last = last.replace((/[+-]+/g), '');

    // console.log([ first, last ]);

    partials = last.split('.');
    if (partials.length === 1) {

      partials.unshift('');
    } else {
      partials = [
        partials.shift(),
        ['.', partials.join('')].join(''),
      ];
    }
    first = [first, partials[0]].join('');
    last = partials[1];

    value = [first, last]
      .join('')
      .replace(
        // trim any sequence of leading zeros into a single one.
        (/(^[+-]?)0+/),
        (match, sign) => [(sign || ''), 0].join('')
      )
      .replace(
        // always ensure a single zero before a leading sole decimal point.
        (/(^[+-]?)\.+/),
        (match, sign) => [(sign || ''), '0.'].join('')
      );
  }
  return value;
}

function sanitizeInputValue(evt) {
  const elmNode = evt.currentTarget;

  const currentValue = elmNode.value;
  const sanitizedValue = getSanitizedValue(currentValue);

  if (currentValue !== sanitizedValue) {
    const diff = sanitizedValue.length - currentValue.length;
    const { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = elmNode;

    elmNode.value = sanitizedValue;

    elmNode.selectionStart =
      (selectionStart + diff > 0) ? selectionStart + diff : selectionStart;
    elmNode.selectionEnd =
      (selectionEnd + diff > 0) ? selectionEnd + diff : selectionEnd;
  }
}

function main() {
  const textInput = document.querySelector('[type="text"]');

  const finalizeBoundFieldValueDebounced = _.debounce(
    stripNeedlessDataFromBoundFieldValue.bind(textInput), 1200
  );
  textInput.addEventListener('input', evt => {
    sanitizeInputValue(evt);
    finalizeBoundFieldValueDebounced();
  });

  // // whithout delayed trimming of trailing dot.
  //
  // document
  //   .querySelector('[type="text"]')
  //   .addEventListener('input', sanitizeInputValue);
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.1/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="... number only ..."/>
```

... and comparing it directly to the number type field ...

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="native number type"/>
```

... and to *Micahel Hamami*'s approach, which hereby got brought into action ...

```js
function sanitizeInputValue({ currentTarget }) {
  currentTarget.value = currentTarget.value.replace(/[^0-9,+,-,.]+/g, "");
}
function main() {
  document
    .querySelector('[type="text"]')
    .addEventListener('input', sanitizeInputValue);
}
main();
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="... number only ..."/>
```

Comment: @nhlinh ... Have a look above into the executable snippet based on *Micahel Hamami*'s approach and compare it to e.g. the one of *h-sifat*. *Micahel*'s approach surely does not cover your requirements. It already fails with e.g. preventing sequences of `+` characters. And while editing long numbers which need to be sanitized one is loosing the caret position.

Comment: I have checked them all. Thank you for your advance

Comment: @nhlinh I've updated  my solution. Check the latest answer. And thanks a lot Peter <3

Answer (score 0):

this will do what you want

```
    let someString = "+123.g";
    let result = someString.replace(/[^0-9,+,-,.]+/g, "");
    console.log(result);
```

for more info on how to use regex check here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how the character class `[...]` works. There are no need to add commas in between each character. Adding`,` actually means you will allow `,` in the input. This also doesn't allow the period character (`.`).

Comment: as I understand from the post , it needs to allow + and - , and yea i will add  (.) if need to allow it. I will edit.

Comment: According to my post, the (+/_) just one exist and only first position of the string

Comment: @MicahelHamami I don't think you addressed my concerns? Why are you adding `,` multiple times? And `,-,` will properly fail, as `-` now have a special meaning, as it isn't at the beginning nor end of the character class.